# Username without Email Extension in PHPMailer

Tags: php, phpmailer

I want to use my university email server to send/receive emails for a project which hosts on our university server. We have true username and password for an email. As an example: Our login username is like "xxxxxx" for email address "xxxxxx@metu.edu.tr" on Squirrelmail. Username has no email extension. I can login and see emails by using these credentials:

> Username: xxxxxx
>
> Password: yyyyyy

Now I set my PHPMailer settings like that:

> define('SMTP_HOST', 'mail.metu.edu.tr');
>
> define('SMTP_PORT', '587');
>
> define('SMTP_SECURE', 'tls');
>
> define('SMTP_USER', 'xxxxxx@metu.edu.tr');
>
> define('SMTP_PASSWORD', 'yyyyyy');

HERE IS THE PHPMAILER ERROR:

```
SMTP -> ERROR: Password not accepted from server: 535 5.7.8 Error: authentication failed: authentication failure 
SMTP -> FROM SERVER:250 2.0.0 Ok 
SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.
```

All settings are correct. The password is correct too.
Because I can send an email to myself by using another hosting with a username "xxxxxx@zzz.com" if I set username(email address) "xxxxxx@zzz.com" on mail server, not "xxxxxx". I think in university hosting they set email adresses without extension. But I really need to send/receive emails on this host.

How can I fix this PHPMailer problem without intervention to host properties.

Comment: I solved this problem with using [Swiftmailer](http://swiftmailer.org/docs/sending.html). It works.

Answer (score 0):

First check if your server accepts passwords plain or md5 hashed. I think you are sending it as plain.

Comment: Yes I was sending as plain text. I tried md5 for password encryption, but it didn't work. I asked admin to learn which kind of encyrption they use.

Comment: I solved this problem with using Swiftmailer. http://swiftmailer.org/docs/sending.html It works.